# AngularJS Ajax Content Loader

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

I am trying to use angularJS to load contents of my HTML from ajax calls.  I would like to have a single method with different parameters to vary ajax/REST uri and display results in different components.  The (non-running version) code looks something like this:

```js
app.controller('ContentController', function($scope, $sce, $http) {
  $scope.FetchContent = function(pageId) {
    let contentUri = 'https://somewhere/restendpoint/?id=' + pageId;

    $http.get(contentUri).then(function(data) {
      return $sce.trustAsHtml(data.data.d[0].Content);
    }
  }
})
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ContentController" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-bind-html="FetchContent('home')"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-bind-html="FetchContent('welcome')"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" ng-bind-html="FetchContent('contact')"></div>
</div>
```

I end up getting tons of ajax calls generated from this. I've tried creating a custom directive, but it updates all elements with same data.  Can anyone give me a pointer?  Thanks!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So.. I was able to get around the repeating ajax calls by using directives instead, and had to embed element Id to lock down the element:

```js
app.controller('ContentController', function($scope, $sce, $http) {
  $scope.FetchContent = function(pageName, elem) {
    var contentUri = 'https://somecontent/restendpoint/?id=' + pageName;
    $http.get(contentUri).then(function (data) {
      $('#' + elem).html(data.data.d[0].HTMLContent);
    });
  }
});


app.directive('loadcontent', function($parse) {
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    link: function ($scope, elem, attrs) {
      elem.ready(function() {
        $scope.$apply(function() {
          var func = $parse(attrs.loadcontent);
          func($scope, elem)
        });
      });
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<div ng-controller="ContentController" class="row">
  <div class="col-md-4" id="e1" loadcontent="FetchContent('home', 'e1')"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="e2" loadcontent="FetchContent('home', 'e2')"></div>
  <div class="col-md-4" id="e3" loadcontent="FetchContent('home', 'e3')"></div>
</div>
```

It works and it inserts unique contents into own elements, but I really don't like the way and can't help but think there's gotta be a better and proper ways to do this... Any ideas from angularJS gurus?

Comment: The difference here is that, in your original code, the digest cycle is going to run those functions assigned to ng-bind-html every time there is a digest cycle.... which triggers another digest cycle, on and on forever and ever. Your directive, on the other hand, simply attached the html to the element using jquery and does not trigger another digest.

Comment: I think another way would be to pull the html down in a service (on the controller, that would be fine if you wanted) and store it in a variable. You could still use ng-bind-html, but use it with the one-time-binding syntax:

ng-bind-html="::$scope.firstSetOfHTML"

That would prevent it from evaluating that directive again.

**I am assuming your version of angularjs includes the one-time binding syntax.

Comment: @DevinFields You should write your approach as an answer. This `loadcontent` directive is like an `ng-init` for asynchronous content. Asynchronous loading should be done in controllers, not from directives.

Comment: @DevinFields Yes please write an example using a service!  Also, is there other ways to select the particular element other than feeding the id as a parameter and using jquery to rewrite the HTML? I am using angularJS v1.7.2

Comment: I will see if I have some time today.